# Generalization of cantors intersection theorem

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $A_1\supset A_2\supset\cdots$ be a sequence of connected compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is it true that their intersection $A=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ is connected also?

Suppose it is not connected then there exists non empty $U\subset A$ which is both open and closed..

So, there exists $M$ open and $N$ closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $U=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}(M\cap A_i)$ and $U=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}(N\cap A_i)$

So, we have $U=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}(M\cap A_i)=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}(N\cap A_i)$

I do not know where to go from here..

Please give only hints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theorem is proved in several places on this site, but since you want only a hint, I’ll see what I can do. Let $V=A\setminus U$; you to make sure that $U$ is not just non-empty, but also a proper subset of $A$, so that $V\ne\varnothing$.

- Show that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint closed sets in $\Bbb R^2$.
- Show that there are disjoint open sets $G$ and $H$ in $\Bbb R^2$ such that $U\subseteq G$ and $V\subseteq H$.
- Show that there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $A_n\subseteq G\cup H$, and get a contradiction by showing that $A_n$ is ... ?

**Added:** For the third point, if there is no such $n$, then for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is a point $x_n\in A_n\setminus(G\cup H)$. Get a contradiction by showing that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ must have a subsequence converging to a point of ... ?

Comment: I think second point is easy... Because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is normal given two disjoint closed sets there exists disjoint open sets containing them

Comment: @cello: Yes, that’s right. For the third point you’ll need to use compactness.

Comment: Yes Yes.. I think i got it.. just filling the gaps.. Once i am done i will write it down.. please see that and let me know if it is correct..

Comment: @cello: I will indeed.

Comment: There is some issue... We have $U=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}(N\cap A_i)$.. $A_i$ are closed and $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $N$ is also closed so intersection is closed and so $U$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.. Now, to see $V=A\setminus U$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ i am facing some difficulty...  We have $V=A\bigcap U^c=A\bigcap\left(\bigcap (M\cap A_i)\right)^c=A\bigcap(\bigcup (M^c\cap A_i^c)=\bigcup (A\cap M^c)$... $M$ is open so $M^c$ is closed.. $A$ is closed so $A\cap M^c$ is closed.. But then how do i say that their union is also closed...

Comment: @cello: There is an open $W$ in $\Bbb R^2$ such that $U=W\cap A$, and it follows that $V=A\setminus W$, which is closed.

Comment: I was unnecessarily considering that unions... 

$U=M\cap A=N\cap A$ for $M$ open and $N$ closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$... As $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $N\cap A=U$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$..We have $V=A\setminus U=A\cap U^c=A\cap (M^c\cup A^c)=A\cap M^c$ which is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $A$ is closed and $M^c$ is closed...

Comment: @cello: Yes, you can demonstrate it that way, too.

Comment: Third point is giving me trouble... Can you say a little bit more than that hint..

Comment: @cello: See if the addition gives you enough of a push.

Comment: We have $x_n\in A_n\setminus(G\cup H)$.. We see that $x_n\in A_1$ for all $n$ as $A_1$ is compact this sequence has a convergenet subsequence converging to an element of $A_1$

Comment: @cello: You can say even more about where the limit has to be. If $k\ge n$, then $x_k\in A_k\subseteq A_n$. Thus, for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we have $\{x_k:k\ge n\}\subseteq A_n$, and hence the limit of the subsequence must be in $A_n$. Since this is true for each $n$, where must the limit actually be?

Comment: Ok Ok.. Limit is actually in $A$

Comment: @cello: The limit is indeed in $A$, but at the same time we have $x_n\in\Bbb R^2\setminus(G\cup H)$ for each $n$. $\Bbb R\setminus(G\cup H)$ is a closed set, and every term of the convergent subsequence is in that set, so where must the limit be? Answer this correctly, and you’ll have your contradiction showing that no such points $x_n$ can exist and therefore that there must be an $n$ with $A_n\subseteq G\cup H$.

Comment: I am sorry,,, We have $x_n\in (G\cup H)^c$ for all $n$ and as $(G\cup H)^c$ is closed we see that limit $x\in (G\cup H)^c$... We have $x\in A$ and $A=U\cup V\subset G\cup H$.. So, we can not have $x\in A$ and $x\notin (G\cup H)$.. Contradiction..

Comment: @cello: That’s right. And that means that some $A_n$ must be a subset of $G\cup H$, and from that you can get a contradiction with the fact that $A_n$ is connected.

Comment: Yes Yes.. I feel so ashamed that i could not catch your hints easily... Thanks againn

Comment: @cello: You’re welcome. Don’t worry about it; it’s happened to all of us. Sometimes one’s mind just doesn’t want to go in the right direction!

Comment: Can we replace compactness of $A_n$ by closedness.. we have used compactness only in case of $A_1$,, As $A_1$ is compact and $x_n\in A_1$ this has a convergent subsequence... $x_n\in x\in A_1$... Now, $x_i\in A_2$ for all $i\geq 2$ and as this sequence has convergent subsequence, and as $A_2$ is closed we have $x\in A_2$... Somthing like this shoudl wor.. compactness is not necessary in case of $A_2 $ and others..

Comment: @cello: All that’s really needed is for at least one $A_n$ to be compact, because then $A_k$ is compact for each $k\ge n$, and we might as well just start with $A_n$ and reduce the problem to the one that we just solved. If we allow **all** of the sets $A_n$ to be non-compact, their intersection could be empty.

Comment: They can be closed and non compact and intersection can still be non empty.. Cantor intersection theorem?

Comment: @cello: Yes, if they’re closed and not compact their intersection *can* be non-empty, but it can also be empty (e.g., if $A_n=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x\ge n\}$). In order to invoke the Cantor intersection theorem to conclude that the intersection is non-empty, we really do need either compactness.

Comment: Ok Ok... I got it... :)

Comment: I have written full answer.. please see

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_1\supset A_2\supset\cdots$ be a sequence of connected compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is it true that their intersection $A=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ is connected also?

Suppose it is not connected then there exists non empty $U\subset A$ which is both open and closed..

So, we have $U=M\cap A=N\cap A$ for $M$ open and $N$ closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$...

As $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $N\cap A=U$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$..

We have $V=A\setminus U=A\cap U^c=A\cap (M^c\cup A^c)=A\cap M^c$ which is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $A$ is closed and $M^c$ is closed...

Clearly $U\cap V=\emptyset $...

As $\mathbb{R}^2$ is normal, there exists two disjoint open sets $G$ and $H$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $U\subset G$ and $V\subset H$..

We claim that $A_n\subset G\cup H$ for some $n$... If this is true then we have a decomposition for $A_n$ contradicting the connectedness of $A_n$..

So, we try to prove that $A_n\subset G\cup H$... Suppsoe we have $A_n\not\subset G\cup H$ for each $n$... Then we have $x_n\in A_n\setminus(G\cup H)$...

Clearly, $x_n\in A_1$ for all $n$.. As  $A_1$ is compact, this has a convergent subsequence  converging to $x$.. So, $x\in A_1$ as $A_1$ is closed..

Clearly, $x_n\in A_2$ for all $n\geq 2$... convergence of subsequence assures that $x\in A_2$..

For similar reasons, we have $x\in A_n $ for all $n$. So, $x\in A$.

Mow, $x_n\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{G\cup H\}$ for all $n$ and as $ \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{G\cup H\}$ is closed we see that subsequence limit $x\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{G\cup H\}$..

But then we have $A=U\cup V\subset G\cup H$.. SO, there can be no element in $A$ that is not in union $G\cup H$..
so, we have a contradiction and $A_n\subseteq G\cup H$  for some $n$...

Done!

Comment: You’re almost there: to finish, it you need to explain why having $A_n\subseteq G\cup H$ is impossible (namely, because $G\cap A_n$ and $H\cap A_n$ are then disjoint, non-empty subsets of $A_n$ that are relatively open in $A_n$, contradicting the connectedness of $A_n$.

Comment: Yes Yes.. I forgot to write that.. Thanks.. @BrianM.Scott